# Opencv 3 with Python3 getting this error: (-215) npoints > 0 in function drawContours

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0

Trying to draw in contours from a list. Here's my code. It fails on the cv2.drawContours function. Is there a way to use the connectedComponentsWithStats function to somehow find all the contours and then draw black pixels over them the way I am trying to because when I use the connectedComponentsWithStats function, it selects the contours I want it to.

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
labelNum, labelImg, contours, GoCs = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(gray)  
for c in contours:
    x,y,w,h,size = c
    if size <= 100:
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, 0, -1)
```

Comment: What's `contours`? Where did it come from? You need to provide a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). | The way you unpack it in `x,y,w,h,size = c`, it doesn't look like output of `cv2.findContours`, and certainly doesn't look like an array of points that `cv2.drawContours` expects.

Comment: I edited the code to show how i unpack it

Comment: What you call `contours` are just statistics (bounding box, area -- just like you already unpack them), not contours (which would each be an array of points).

Comment: Is there a way to use the connectedComponentsWithStats function to somehow find all the contours and then draw black pixels over them the way I am trying to? Because when I use the connectedComponentsWithStats function it selected the things I want it to versus just using findContours.

Comment: Can you please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/44087581/edit) your question and update it with your previous comment? Also attach a sample input image you're testing with.